# asp.net vb 2008: searching in grid results

Tags: asp.net

We have a client who wants the following:

1. display all equipment in a grid
2. when entering a search string in two textboxes which target different columns, automatically search on either entered string
3. grid holds approximately 5000 items and must be paged and header-sortable

I have just made the very unwelcome discovery that the FindItemWithText method is not available in an ASP Listview.

QUESTIONS:

What is the best data container to use to enable this kind of searching?

How can it be implemented?

THANKS

Answer (score 0):

[Infragistics webdatagrid](http://samples.infragistics.com/2010.3/WebFeatureBrowser/Default.aspx) would be your best bet. It's darn expensive, but one heck of a component to have in your arsenal.